# what data structure does model formula operator in R create?

Tags: r

The [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) makes several mentions of the model formula operator, but fails to define or explain anything about the formula class.

I am having a hard time finding anything that documents the semantics of the ~ operator from either official or unofficial sources.

In particular, I am not interested in information like is provided in [the formula function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula) (*"An expression of the form y ~ model is interpreted as a specification that the response y is modelled by a linear predictor specified symbolically by model."*) or usage scenarios, I'd like to understand what kind of data structure I am creating when using it and how I could inspect and dissect it on the REPL.

Comment: any suggestions for a more fitting title to this question are welcome

Comment: the operator help file is `?\`~\`` or `?tilde` which is pretty short, `as.list(y ~ x)` will show you that the operator, left side, and right side are `?name` objects or symbols. not exactly sure what more you are looking for, a formula isn't very complex, more useful for referencing objects without evaluation

Comment: I didn't vote to close. Maybe you can edit to "how do I work with objects of class 'formula'" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this helps, but: it's a `language` object — i.e. R parses the input but doesn't try to evaluate any of the components — with class "formula"

```r
> f <- a ~ b + (c + d)
> str(f)
Class 'formula'  language a ~ b + (c + d)
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

If you want to work with these objects, you need to know that it is essentially stored as a tree, where the parent node, an operator or function (`~`, `+`, `(`) , can be extracted as the first element and the child nodes (as many as the 'arity' of the function/operator) can be extracted as elements 2..n, i.e.

- `f[[1]]` is `~`
- `f[[2]]` is `a` (the first argument, i.e. the LHS of the formula)
- `f[[3]]` is `b + (c+d)`
- `f[[3]][[1]]` is `+`
- `f[[3]][[2]]` is `b`

... and so on.

The chapter on *Expressions* in Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html) gives a more complete description.

This is also discussed (more opaquely) in the *R Language Manual*, e.g.

- [Expression objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Expression-objects)
- [Direct manipulation of language objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Direct-manipulation-of-language-objects)

@user2554330 points out that formulas also typically have associated *environments*; that is, they carry along a pointer to the environment in which they were created

Comment: The other important aspect is the attached environment.  Functions using formulas usually have a `data` argument, and look for formula variables in `data` first, then in the formula's environment (recursively, since environments have parents).  When you create the formula object the environment is the one you are working in (which confuses people who create formulas in functions).

Comment: So this is really just a symbolic programming facility then and further semantics (of the tilde at least) are superimposed solely by code that processes a formula?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your definition of "symbolic programming facility" is, but the rest of it seems correct.  The primary consumers of R formulas are `model.matrix()` and `model.frame()`, although they are used in other contexts (e.g.  statistical tests such as `t.test()`, `lattice`, `ggformula` packages)